# Capybara: undefined method 'visit' - Test is already in spec/features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have just started with RSpec and Capybara but got stuck on my first test.
Here's me test code located in `spec/features/pages_spec.rb` :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Pages", :type => :request do
    describe "About Page" do
        it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
            visit '/pages/about'
            page.should have_content('About Us')
        end
    end
end
```

Running the test i get the following error :

```
01:06:59 - INFO - Running: spec

F

Failures:

1) Pages About Page should have the content 'About Us'
 Failure/Error: visit '/pages/about'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method 'visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Pages::AboutPage:0x007f975afe7380>
 # ./spec/features/pages_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02569 seconds (files took 1.65 seconds to load)

1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/features/pages_spec.rb:5 # Pages About Page should have the content 'About Us'
```

I've been searching about this for about an hour and everywhere I find the solution of moving the test code from `spec/requests` to `spec/features`.

I've also seen this here : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md which most of the solution suggests and it is not recommended to use.

```
# not recommended!
RSpec.configure do |c|
    c.include Capybara::DSL, :file_path => "spec/requests"
end
```

I've no idea how to proceed. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: it's a basic question but have you actually included Capybara gem in your Gemfile and run `bundle install` ?

Comment: Yes, Of course I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either take `:type => :request` out of the describe block (which overrides the spec type determined from the directory location) or change it to `:type => :feature`.

Comment: Oh, Small thing I overlooked. Thanks a lot :)